# Problema con select para mostrar registros

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy desarrollando un sistema de gestión de activo fijo y tengo una consulta que me trae información de distintas tablas, una de las tablas llamada `kz_sgaf_distribdebajas` (distribución de bajas) guarda registros sobre las bajas de activo que se han hecho a una adquisición de activo, donde me traigo el saldo minimo de todas las bajas que se han hecho a un mismo activo y me lo muestre, pero necesito que cuando el registro con ese saldo sea 0 no me lo muestre, trato de colocar en el where `saldo_adqui > 0`, pero me trae la baja de activo anterior, antes de haber llegado a 0

salida `kz_sgaf_distribdebajas`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se dan cuenta yo hice dos bajas para un mismo activo y en la consulta yo hago que me traiga el saldo mínimo de los dos, pero si el saldo llega a cero no me lo traiga.

Entrada:

```
SELECT distinct adq.id_adqui, con.id_activo, con.cod_activo, con.descripcion_activo, emp.nombre_empr, cat.nombre_categ, 
CASE WHEN db.saldo_adqui is null THEN adq.cantidad_adqui ELSE MIN(db.saldo_adqui) END as saldo_restante
FROM kz_sgaf_adquisicionesaf adq
LEFT JOIN kz_sgaf_distribdebajas db ON db.id_adqui = adq.id_adqui
INNER JOIN kz_sgaf_configaf con ON con.id_activo = adq.id_activo
INNER JOIN kz_sgaf_empresas emp ON emp.id_empr = con.id_empr
INNER JOIN kz_sgaf_categorias cat ON cat.id_categ = con.id_categ
group by adq.id_adqui;
```

Salida:

```
100 102 12312312    Maquinaria Pesada   Empresa Uno Categoría Uno   0
101 102 12312312    Maquinaria Pesada   Empresa Uno Categoría Uno   5
102 102 12312312    Maquinaria Pesada   Empresa Uno Categoría Uno   500
```

Necesito que ese primer registro no salga, ya que tiene una valor de 0 y no necesito mostrarlo al usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución podría ser hacer un `SELECT` de esa misma consulta y en el where filtrar por `saldo_restante` > 0. Es decir:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT distinct adq.id_adqui, con.id_activo, con.cod_activo, con.descripcion_activo, emp.nombre_empr, cat.nombre_categ, 
 CASE WHEN db.saldo_adqui is null THEN adq.cantidad_adqui ELSE MIN(db.saldo_adqui) END as saldo_restante
 FROM kz_sgaf_adquisicionesaf adq
 LEFT JOIN kz_sgaf_distribdebajas db ON db.id_adqui = adq.id_adqui
 INNER JOIN kz_sgaf_configaf con ON con.id_activo = adq.id_activo
 INNER JOIN kz_sgaf_empresas emp ON emp.id_empr = con.id_empr
 INNER JOIN kz_sgaf_categorias cat ON cat.id_categ = con.id_categ
 group by adq.id_adqui) as bajas_valorizadas
WHERE saldo_restante > 0
```

Comment: Lo intente, pero me sale esto `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias 0.000 sec`

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias, la sub consulta tenia que tener su alias, por eso me tiraba el error, pero tu me ayudaste mucho.

Comment: Cierto es, no tengo un mysql aquí y no he podido hacer la prueba. Me alegro que haya podido ayudarte!